# Is every closed point of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ contained in a line $\mathbb{A}^1_L \subset \mathbb A^n_k$, where $k \subset L$ is an algebraic extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, not necessarily algebraically closed. Is it true that any closed point $p \in \mathbb{A}^n_k$ is contained in a line $\mathbb A^1_L \subset \mathbb A^n_k$, for some algebraic field extension $k \subset L$?

If $k$ is algebraically closed, the situation is clear: By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz every closed point $p$ corresponds to a maximal ideal of the form $(x_i - a_i \,|\, 1 \leq i \leq n)$, and the ideal $(x_i - a_i \,|\, 1 \leq i \leq n-1)$ defines a line containing $p$.

But if $k$ is not algebraically closed, this does not work. For example, consider the point $p \in \mathbb A^2_{\mathbb Q}$ which corresponds to the maximal ideal $(x^2 + 1, y^2 - 2) \subset \mathbb Q[x,y]$. Then the closed subscheme $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}$, given by $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)[y]$, contains $p$. So here we have to consider the algebraic extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(i)$.

But I don't know if this (or a similar) procedure works for *every* closed point?

Comment: Why wouldn't this work for every closed point? The ideal of a closed point $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ is just given by $(m_{a_1}(x_1),\cdots,m_{a_n}(x_n))$ where $m_{a_i}(x_i)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a_i\in\overline{k}$ over $k$ in the variable $x_i$.

Comment: If $a\in L^n$ then there is $b\in k^n$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j=0$ iff $\dim(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j k) < n$ which is not always the case. For example it works with $k=\Bbb{Q},L=\Bbb{Q}(i),a=(i,-i)$ but it fails with $a=(i,1)$. A sufficient non-necessary condition is $[L:k]< n$.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, that works. I missed that every maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is generated by the minimal polynomials, thanks!

Comment: @reuns The field $L$ is not fixed. but is allowed to vary for different points $p$.

Comment: $p$ is fixed thus the field generated by its coordinates

Comment: @reuns So do you mean, that not every point will be contained in a hyperplane $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}_k \subset \mathbb{A}^n_k$, defined by $b \in k^n$? That is exactly why I think we should allow affine lines over some field extension. IMO KReiser's comment solved this.

Comment: If so then your question was trivial since the beginning (and $(x_1^2+1,x_2^2+1)$ is not a prime ideal, it is $(x_1^2+1,x_2-x_1)$, ie. $m_{a_2}(x_1,x_2)$ is the $k[x_1]/(m_{a_1}(x_1))$ minimal polynomial of $a_2$)